# Force scrolling of inner div when outer has max-height?

Tags: css

Here's the setup:

```css
#out {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#in {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: scroll-y;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="out">
  <input value="stuff here that i don't know the height of">
  <div id="in">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid eius voluptatibus tenetur cumque, incidunt maxime, cum dolorem sed corporis. Iste illum eaque enim cum quo saepe dicta perferendis incidunt. Accusamus.
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see that the red box runs off the bottom. I want a scrollbar to appear instead, and the 5-pixel blue padding should be visible on the bottom.

How can I do this?

Note that I don't know the exact height of the red box. If there's less content, there should be no scrollbar, and the total height will be less than 250px.

Comment: Are you trying to get the "stuff here that i don't know the height of" to scroll as well, or just the "#in" div?

Comment: @McGlothlin Nope. I only want `#in` to scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Based on your updated question, you can use `display:flex` instead of the `max-height` that I initially suggested and keep the `overflow:auto`.

```css
#out {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#in {
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 240px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="out">
  <input value="stuff here that i don't know the height of">
  <div id="in">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid eius voluptatibus tenetur cumque, incidunt maxime, cum dolorem sed corporis. Iste illum eaque enim cum quo saepe dicta perferendis incidunt. Accusamus.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know the height of `#in`, nor max-height. There will be other stuff inside `#out`, but I only want the `#in` part to scroll. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer.  `flex` is really a perfect use-case for this kind of thing, unless you have to support older browsers (< IE11, I believe).

Comment: That'll have to do. We're dropping support for IE9-10 in January (hopefully), so they can live with some ugliness until then :-) Thank you!

Comment: I have done this dynamically with JavaScript, but there's no way I know of to do this without setting it exactly by the pixel, as done here. You could set the `max-height: inherit` for `#in`, but that doesn't account for the `input` field or any other stuff you might have in the `#out` div.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so we have a div `#out` with a max-height to get scrollbars. The `#in` div will add the blue border and the `#scroll` div contains the content that will scroll on `overflow-y`

```css
#out {
  width: 100px;
  max-height: 250px;
  position:relative;
  background:blue;
  padding:5px;
}

#in {
   background-color: red;
   height:240px
}
#scroll{
 height:100%;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="out">
  <div id="in">
   <div id="scroll">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid eius voluptatibus tenetur cumque, incidunt maxime, cum dolorem sed corporis. Iste illum eaque enim cum quo saepe dicta perferendis incidunt. Accusamus.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite. You've put a max-height on the `#scroll`. I don't know the height. There's going to be other junk in there.

Comment: Ok but you'll never get a scrollbar if there's no height set! Some of the divs containing content need a max-height!

Answer (score 0):

```
#out {
  width: 100px;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
}

#in {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 245px;
}
```

Comment: My actual setup is a bit more complicated. `#in` doesn't just contain a blob of text, and a simple border won't work.

Comment: @mpen No problem...just make the max-height on the #in div 5px less then the #out div. That will account for the 5 pixels of padding at the bottom. Updating my answer in a second...

Comment: Try the new code above. It should work for you. As long as you keep the max height of the inner div 5px less than the max-height of the outer div, it shouldn't cover the bottom 5px of the outer div.

Comment: I still don't know the height of `#in`. It won't be 250 minus border-width (which is 240 btw).